# I can't configure firewalld with my custom rule xml

Tags: centos-7, firewalld

Centos7:

I dropped my xml in /etc/firewalld/services
when running 
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=rules.xml`
all i get is "Error: INVALID_SERVICE: rules"

When running `firewall-cmd --permanent --get-services`it doesn't list my xml rules.

What do i need to do to get my service recognized?

Answer (score 2):

Try reloading your firewalld with service commands:

```
# service firewalld restart
```

and remove `.xml` extension from `--add-service` option

Comment: one additional change I had to make was remove any/all xml comments (ie, `<!--- bleh --->`)